# How do you manage the Gutenberg block previews in the admin area?

Tags: block-editor, twitter-bootstrap, previews

How can I manage Gutenberg block previews in the admin area?

Example:

If I have a block developed on bootstrap and with my custom css, in the admin area do you load bootstrap and your css to get the preview?

Comment: If you want the block to look identical in the editor as on the front-end then yes you'd need to load bootstrap in de editor assets as well. The entire editor will change because of bootstrap though so what I always do is write a custom editor.css mimicking the most important bits I need so that the editor looks LIKE the front-end to show what is going on but is not a 100% copy of it.